# Which harmonics can be used to reduce the amplitude of the fundamental waveform?

Tags: trigonometry, harmonic-analysis

A question that has been bugging me for a while is this:

Say we have 
$$f_1(x) = \sin(x) $$

If we subtract a third-order sine wave from this sine-wave, of amplitude $1-2/\sqrt{3}$ we get

$$f_2(x) = \sin(x) -(1-2/\sqrt{3})\cdot \sin(3x)$$

If you plot $f_2$, you will see that it is bound by $0.866$.

I am wondering what is so special about the third order harmonic that it can reduce the amplitude of the sine wave.  To my knowledge, no other harmonics can do this.

Thanks!

Comment: The maximum of $\sin(x)-0.06\sin(5x)$ is about $0.9511.$ I believe any odd harmonic can reduce the maximum, though the effect is less for higher harmonics. Combinations of multiple odd harmonics (of order 5 or higher) can reduce the maximum further than single harmonics.

Comment: Hi David.  Do you know if there is a limit then to how much the fundamental can be reduced with harmonics?

Comment: Presumably there must be a limit, since you can't reduce the absolute value of $1$ by more than $1.$ I don't know what the limit is.

Comment: Ah........Thanks. I think that the limit is much larger than $1$. I just don't know how to prove it. I would really like to see a proof, but I don't know how to phrase the question well enough to find the answer.